# Rave Reports - Access Violation in rtl150.bpl on intToStr or StrToFloat

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

20/01/2012 I have now given up on rave and reworked the reports in FastReport.

I have now got the report working by downloading DelphiXE2 and re-compiling the report with Rave version 10.

I am Using RAD Studio XE Version 15.0.3953.35171 with RV90RAVBE Build 100610.

1)

I am converting an old delphi2005 project to DelphiXE and encountering problems in Rave.

The error message is

```
Access Violation at address 5003c0a0 in module ‘rtl50.bpl’. Read of address 000006F9
```

I believe this is happening in a rave  `OnGetText` Event.

The data is a floating point number representing duration in days and I am going to display in days, hours, minutes, seconds.

Running the code without the event in displays the correct number but as soon as I put in the `strToFloat` conversion it fails.

I have sandboxed the code and sometimes get a failure when introducing an `intToStr` and sometimes a `strToFloat`

The specific line of code that fails is

```
tmp := StrToFloat(value);
```

Here is the code:

```
{ Event for Duration.OnGetText }
function Duration_OnGetText(Self: TRaveDataText; var Value: string);
var
  tmp :Extended;
  days :Integer;
  hours: Integer;
  minutes: Integer;
  seconds: Integer;
begin
  if(value <> '') then
    tmp := StrToFloat(value);

  days := Trunc(tmp);
  tmp := Frac(tmp)*24;//fraction of a day in hours
  hours := Trunc(tmp);
  tmp := Frac(tmp)*60;
  minutes := Trunc(tmp);
  tmp := Frac(tmp)*60;
  seconds := Trunc(tmp);

  Value := IntToStr(days) + ':' + IntToStr(hours)+ ':' + IntToStr(minutes)+ ':' + IntToStr(seconds);
end;
```

1. Is it possible to set break points and debug in rave? I can’t find anything in the help about debugging.

Comment: Please read this about how to format code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the formatting changes I made above (particularly indentation levels to indicate blocks), and then my annotated code below, and the problem should be pretty easy to figure out. (Stepping through with the debugger might have helped as well.)

```
{ Event for Duration.OnGetText }
function Duration_OnGetText(Self: TRaveDataText; var Value: string);
var
  tmp :Extended;
  days :Integer;
  hours: Integer;
  minutes: Integer;
  seconds: Integer;
begin
  if(value <> '') then           
    tmp := StrToFloat(value);  // This only gets called if Value <> ''
                               // Note that value could contain 'Pete', '123.45', 'Argh!', etc.

  // This gets called no matter what the value of tmp is, 
  // whether it's a valid floating point created by StrToFloat
  // above, or a random value picked up from memory (since it
  // may never have been initialized above. The same applies to 
  // every line of code that follows.
  days := Trunc(tmp);   

  tmp := Frac(tmp)*24;//fraction of a day in hours
  hours := Trunc(tmp);
  tmp := Frac(tmp)*60;
  minutes := Trunc(tmp);
  tmp := Frac(tmp)*60;
  seconds := Trunc(tmp);

  Value := IntToStr(days) + ':' + IntToStr(hours)+ ':' + IntToStr(minutes)+ ':' + IntToStr(seconds);
end;
```

You're not handling the failure of `StrToFloat` if `Value` is something other than a floating point value. You might try using `StrToFloatDef` with a default value, or `TryStrToFloat` and testing the boolean return value to see if you should proceed or exit.

Your code as posted doesn't compile, btw. You have an extra `end OnGetText;` at the bottom that's mismatched with the code above. Please post actual, compilable code with your questions, especially those about exceptions or access violations you're trying to track down.

Also, as a suggestion - replace your final line of code with

```
Value := Format('%d:%d:%d:%d', [days, hours, minutes, seconds]);
```